# Limiting menu management

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, menu

I am creating a website with Drupal 6.x that will have several content editors and several menus. I would like to somehow lock down their ability to add a piece of content as a top level navigation item.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Additionally, are there any modules that make the menu drop down in the content creation page a bit more user friendly?

Comment: Can you specify what you would consider more "user friendly"? There are literally [dozens of modules](http://drupal.org/project/modules?filters=drupal_core%3A87&solrsort=sis_project_release_usage%20desc&text=menu) that modify the behavior of menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found several modules which look helpful for enhancing the menu system:

http://drupal.org/project/menu_editor
http://drupalmodules.com/module/menu-weight-assist
http://drupalmodules.com/module/ez-menu
http://drupalmodules.com/module/better-menu

Answer (score 0):

The [menu settings per content type module](http://drupal.org/project/ctm) allows you to determine which content types may be added to each of your menus.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use the menu system? It's possible that you can use the views module to get something more flexible.